# Is there a way to make a custom textfield in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to make a textfield with a fiexd and a card for an each letter?

[image]

when each letter card is filled, the cursor travels to the next one.
Are there any right ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries available fixing this problem. You can take a look  at [here](https://github.com/yogeshpaliyal/Speld).